# S3 client.GetObject behaviour if read beyond fileSize

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I need to read a file from S3 in blocks.
I am using the following code :

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, filePath);
rangeObjectRequest.setRange(startOffset, startOffset + length - 1);
S3Object objectPortion = s3Client.getObject(request);
S3ObjectInputStream stream = objectPortion.getObjectContent();
byte[] outputBuffer = ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);
```

I wish to know what will happen if the range which I give is not in the bounds of the file, for eg. , if the file size is 2MB and I set the range to be fetched as
startOffset = 3MB, length = 1MB
will I get an exception or will it simply return a stream with 0 bytes.

I understand I could have checked this myself but I currently dont have access to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying API returns an error, so the library should throw an [exception](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException.html) with an [ErrorCode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException.html#getErrorCode--) of `InvalidRange`.

Here's the raw response from the API itself for request for bytes 80-90 of a 66 byte object.  XML formatted for readability.

```
HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
x-amz-request-id: xxx
x-amz-id-2: xxx
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 19:44:36 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidRange</Code>
  <Message>The requested range is not satisfiable</Message>
  <RangeRequested>bytes=80-90</RangeRequested
  <ActualObjectSize>66</ActualObjectSize>
  <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
  <HostId>xxx</HostId>
</Error>
```